We define the normal direction of Ω. Now if Ω is convex, why it is equivalent to the following set?
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be closed and $x^* \in \Omega$. Define the normal directions of
$\Omega$ at $x^*$ is given by  $N(x^*) = \{d\in \mathbb R^n|\limsup_{x\to^\Omega x^*} \frac{\langle d, x-x^* \rangle}{\Vert x-x^* \Vert} \le 0 \}$
, where $x\to^\Omega x^*$ means $x\to x^*$ with $x \in \Omega$.
If in addtion $\Omega$ is convex, then please show that $N(x^*) = \{d\in \mathbb R^n|\langle d, x-x^* \rangle \le 0  , \forall x \in \Omega \}$
It is easy to show the right set is in the left set, but I have problem in showing that the set $N(x^*)$ is in the right set. The thing is if $x\to^\Omega x^*$, we can get $\langle d, x-x^* \rangle \le 0$. However, I don't know how to extend it to the whole $\Omega$.
And by the way, I wonder why the normal directions of $\Omega$ can be defined like this: $N(x^*) = \{d\in \mathbb R^n|\limsup_{x\to^\Omega x^*} \frac{\langle d, x-x^* \rangle}{\Vert x-x^* \Vert} \le 0 \}$

Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Take $d$ that is not in the second set, i.e., there is $x\in \Omega$ such that $\langle d, x-x^*\rangle >0$.
Now define the sequence $x_k := x^* + \frac1k (x-x^*)$.
Since $\Omega$ is convex, it follows $x_k \in \Omega$ and $x_k \to^\Omega x^*$.
Then
$$
\frac{ \langle d, x_k -x^* \rangle}{ \|x_k -x^*\|} = \frac{ \langle d, x-x^*\rangle }{\|x-x^*\|}  >0,
$$
and $d$ is not in the first set.
